# Number Theory Problem

Tags: number-theory

Let $p = 17843$.

Find all $16^{th}$ roots of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Please share your thoughts, effort and progress made towards solving it yourself (so that we don't feel as if you're asking us to do your homework for you).

Comment: I was trying to solve it by the primitive root theorem

Comment: Share - in details, and **in your post**.

Comment: I find out its order which is 23 by Euler's theorem

Comment: More details, and **IN YOUR POST**.

Comment: @barakmanos My eyes widened as if someone just suddenly shouted at me xD

Comment: So I was trying to do this problem by this theorem:
a has square root mod p if and only if a^p-1/2 congruent to -1 mod p

Comment: @AvZ: I tried to whisper it two comments earlier, but apparently it went unheard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $17843=7\times 2549$.

Find the sixteenth roots of  $2 \bmod 7$ and $\bmod 2549$ and then stitch them back together via CRT.

To find the sixteenth roots of $2\bmod 2549$ notice it is a primitive root, so if you express the multiplicative group $\bmod 2549$ as $2,2^2,2^3\dots 2^{2548}=1$ you want the powers which give a multiple of $2548$ when multiplied by $16$. So you want the numbers of the form $2^{637k}$

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little? It will be helpful :)

Comment: CRT=Cathode Ray Tube? xD

Comment: 19 × 97 = 1843.

Comment: @AvZ: CRT: Chinese Remainder Theorem

Comment: @EllieJohnson I know. I was just kidding.